# Call same function many times and process combined result set

Tags: node.js, function, asynchronous, code-duplication

I have a requirement to make several API requests and then do some processing on the combines result sets. In the example below, you can see that 3 requests are made (to /create) by duplicating the same request code however I would like to be able to specify how many to make. For example, I may wish to run the same API call 50 times.

How can I make n calls without duplicating the API call function n times?

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback){
        request.post('http://localhost:3000/create')
            .send(conf)
            .end(function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err, null);
                }
                callback(null, res.body.id);
            });
    },
    function(callback){
        request.post('http://localhost:3000/create')
            .send(conf)
            .end(function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err, null);
                }
                callback(null, res.body.id);
            });
    },
    function(callback){
        request.post('http://localhost:3000/api/store/create')
            .send(conf)
            .end(function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err, null);
                }
                callback(null, res.body.id);
            });
    }
],
function(err, results){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
 // do stuff with results
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, wrap the code that you want to call many times in a function:

```
var doRequest = function (callback) {
    request.post('http://localhost:3000/create')
        .send(conf)
        .end(function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err);
            }
            callback(null, res.body.id);
        });
}
```

Then, use the [async.times](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#times) function:

```
async.times(50, function (n, next) {
    doRequest(function (err, result) {
      next(err, result);
    });
}, function (error, results) {
  // do something with your results
}
```

Comment: `async.times` function doesn't seem to parallel though

Comment: It's doesn't wait for one call to complete before calling the next one. That's the difference from `async.timesSeries`.

Comment: Why does the callback have a name `next`? Behavior of this function is not evident from documentation...

Comment: Just have done a test. async.times is the answer! it acts exactly the way required. `next` callback name in documentation is misleading. It is just a callback to confirm end of operation and return result.

Comment: The `next` callback is not misleading given the way those iterator functions are implemented in `async` library IMO, because it's being used to call the next step. I think what may have confused you is the fact that the `parallel` concept in `async` library doesn't mean that all 50 calls are going to be executed at the same time. It just mean that each step is going to be called without waiting for the previous step callback return.

Comment: That's it. 50 setTimeouts are called almost simultaneously and as a result they end at almost the same time. So what is next step if none is waiting? 'Next' is logical for timesSeries()

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with as many *references* to the function as you need tasks in your workload.  Then pass them to `async.parallel`.  For example:

```
var async = require("async");

var slowone = function (callback) {
        setTimeout(function () {
                callback(null, 1);
        }, 1000);
};

async.parallel(
        dd(slowone, 100), 
        function (err, r) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
        }
);

// Returns an array with count instances of value.
function dd(value, count) {
        var result = [];

        for (var i=0; i<count; i++) {
                result.push(value);
        }

        return result;
}
```

Note again that there is only one instance of the slow running function, in spite of there being many *references* to it.